# PHP Desktop Chrome has stopped working

Tags: php, codeigniter, inno-setup, exe

i have used `php desktop application` for `codeigniter` project its work properly

now i used `inno setup` to create setup for `php desktop application`

inno setup : [step for inno setup](https://phpocean.com/tutorials/design-and-illustration/create-your-first-desktop-application-with-php-and-php-desktop/4)

i have follow all the step and setup was create but after execute application not run and below error generate

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: phpdesktop-chrome.exe
  Application Version:  31.8.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    546f0770
  Fault Module Name:    libcef.dll
  Fault Module Version: 3.1650.1562.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   52d3dd6e
  Exception Code:   80000003
  Exception Offset: 001179c0
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

here is screenshot :
[image]

Comment: Nothing to do with CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 – Reinstall google chrome or upgrade google chrome**

```
(1) Go to “control panel –> Programs and features –> Select google chrome” to uninstall it.
(2) Now go to this path in your local computer “C:Program FilesGoogle” and delete “Chrome” folder. If you are using 64 bit computer then path of the folder will be ” C:Program Files (x86)Google”.
(3) Now, Go here and download latest version of google chrome and install it.
(4) Restart your computer after reinstalling google chrome and check whether problem is resolved or not.
```

**Method 2 – Clear cookies and disable unwanted extensions and apps**

```
(1) Click on this icon (Top right side of gogole chrome) –> go to settings –> Show advanced settings
```